# unable to connect to MSSQL using PHP and Laravel in XAMPP. Windows OS

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I am working on php version 8.2 using laravel 10. I am working on windows using XAMPP.

I am facing an issue connecting PHP to MSSQL server. I have downloaded drivers from microsoft and copied below files.

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
```

to location: `C:\\xampp1\\php\\ext`

and also updated php.ini file with follwing entries

```
extension=sqlsrv
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64`
```

I can see mssql is enable in php info. I can see following entries:

`pdo_sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv support  enabled ExtensionVer    5.11.0-beta1+16628`

When I run the command in terminal `php artisan migrate` I get the following errors:

1

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
> PDOException::("could not find driver")

2

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
> PDO::__construct("dblib:host=XX.XX.XX.XX:3306;dbname=XXXXX;charset=utf8",
> "XXXXX", "^XXXXX", [])

Please advise me in resolving the issue in resolving my MSSQL connection issue.

Comment: Aside... are you sure you're wanting to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server? The port number in your error message is 3306, which is the default port for a MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. I have fixed the port to 1433. Still the error says "could not find driver". Please advise